# VBA Sub to locate a cell based on Top row and First Column

Tags: vba, excel

My top row is state's Name such as VA CA, first column contains industry code. Need a VBA sub that after I click this Button named Locate, a msgbox asks user to put the State name, a second msgbox asks user to put the industry code, vba finds which column and row that state and industry is at, locate the value based on these 2 coordinates input.

```
Sub Locate()
Dim siccode As Integer
Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound, rngFound2 As Range
Dim r As Double
Dim c As Double
Dim states, cellvalue As String

siccode = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter 2 digit SIC code: ", Title:="SIC   Code", Default:="SIC here")
states = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter State name: ", Title:="State Name", Default:="State Name here")

Set rngSearch = Range("A:BB")
Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:="siccode", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
 If rngFound Is Nothing Then
 MsgBox "No claims at all"
 Else
 MsgBox rngFound.Row
 End If

Set rngSearch = Range("A:BB")
Set rngFound2 = rngSearch.Find(What:="states", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If rngFound2 Is Nothing Then
 MsgBox "No Claims at all"
 Else
 MsgBox rngFound2.Column
 End If

cellvalue = ActiveSheet.Cells(rngFound.Row, rngFound2.Column).value
MsgBox (cellvalue)
End Sub
```

it works fine till the if part, no matter what input it is, it always shows no claims at all.

Comment: You need a sub that does something, but have you tried to do this yourself? Where's your code? Where are you stuck? What does it do or not do?

Comment: This isn't a free coding service, show your research efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your search line, why is siccode in quotes? Its an integer variable, not a string. Same thing with states, that is a variable.

```
Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:="siccode", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

Set rngFound2 = rngSearch.Find(What:="states", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
```

Try removing the quotation marks.

Comment: Good catch! Thanks! btw though, I actually don't want my msgbox to return the ros number and column number, I just want the  final cell value result being returned, how should I do so?